# primeng panel menu click event

Tags: angular, primeng

```
<p-panelMenu [model]="items" [style]="{'width':'300px'}" (click)="clicked($event)"></p-panelMenu>`<p-dialog header="Title" [(visible)]="display">
page 1
```

`

this is my ts
    `  click: any;

```
display: boolean = false;

constructor() {

 }

 items: MenuItem[];

     ngOnInit() {
         this.items = [
             {
                 label: 'Chapter 1',
                 icon: 'fa-file-o',
                 items: [{
                         label: 'Chapter1.1', 
                         icon: 'fa-plus',
                         items: [
                             {label: 'Chapter1.1.1'},
                             {label: 'Chapter1.1.2'},
                         ]
                     },
                     {label: 'Chapter1.2'},
                     {label: 'Chapter1.3'}
                 ]
             },
             {
                 label: 'Chapter 2',
                 icon: 'fa-edit',
                 items: [
                     {label: 'Chapter 2.1', icon: 'fa-mail-forward'},
                     {label: 'Chapter 2.2', icon: 'fa-mail-reply'}
                 ]
             }


         ];
     }
     clicked(event=1) {
         console.log("event",event)

            this.display=true;


    }
}
```

`

[panel menu image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8ugG.png)

This is the picture of my panel menu.
On click of each chapter i need to display a different panel for each different chapter how do i give event for each.can anyone help me with this.

Comment: use [ngStyle] instead of [style]

Comment: what do you mean by this "display a different panel for each different chapter"? not getting your point.

Comment: if u can see the image i have given naming as chapter 1 ,2 like that.And different panel means in primeng there are panels right.so onclick of each chapter i need to display a different panel.

Comment: Your question is not clear, what's inside p-dialog? why there is no closing tag for p-dialog? This method syntax is incorrect clicked(event=1) , correct syntax is clicked(event). This defect seems related to your issue https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/3309

Comment: i need a click event so on click of different chapter (as shown in image)i need to display a different paragraphs

Comment: You may want to use command callback: https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/menumodel

Comment: Have you able to solve this? if yes solution please and if not other plugin you have used

Answer (score 6):

Bind funcion with the menu items like this

> this.items = [
>         {
>           label: 'Item 1',
>           command: (event) => { this.clickItem1(); }
>         }]

Create functions that you provided earlier

> clickItem1() {
>       console.log('clicked');
>     }